# How can I get SUM result as an alias in MYSQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```sql
    SELECT
        date_format(LEFT(CAST(REQDT AS UNSIGNED),8),'%Y-%m-%d') AS REQDT,
        count(SVCE_DOMAIN) COUNTSVCE


        FROM BC_HISTORY
        where reqid ='MSYS'
        
        group by date_format(LEFT(CAST(REQDT AS UNSIGNED),8),'%Y-%m-%d');
```

The code I wrote above results show like this.

[image]

I want to know how to Sum numbers in the column 'COUNTSVCE'.
The column 'COUNTSVCE' is an alias of `count(SVCE_DOMAIN)`.
`Rollup` function might be a good solution but I can't use it in my JAVA query
so I get the result as alias.
Thank you.

Comment: Adding sample input/output data to your question would be very helpful towards getting an answer here.

Comment: PS. Do you really need in UNION? Do you want to receive 2 separate rows - one with total amount and another with filtered one? or you need in one row - (date, total, filtered)? Also I do not see GROUP BY clause - COUNT() without it but with another column selected looks strange.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As you say the former code is too long so i changed the code. If you don't mind  I hope you to check my changed code. Thank you

Comment: *Rollup function might be a good solution but I can't use in my JAVA query so I get the result as alias.* ROLLUP is not a function but GROUP BY option. I don't understand why you cannot use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you need either in

```
SELECT total.*
FROM ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LEFT(CAST(reqdt AS UNSIGNED),8),'%Y-%m-%d') AS reqdt,
              COUNT(svce_domain) countsvce
       FROM bc_history
       GROUP BY reqdt
     UNION ALL
       SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LEFT(CAST(reqdt AS UNSIGNED),8),'%Y-%m-%d') AS reqdt,
              COUNT(svce_domain) countsvce
       FROM bc_history
       WHERE reqid ='MSYS'
       GROUP BY reqdt
     ) AS total
```

or in

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LEFT(CAST(reqdt AS UNSIGNED),8),'%Y-%m-%d') AS reqdt,
       COUNT(svce_domain) total_count,
       SUM(reqid ='MSYS') msys_count
FROM bc_history
GROUP BY reqdt
```

---

**UPDATE according to altered question**

Why you cannot use

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LEFT(CAST(reqdt AS UNSIGNED),8),'%Y-%m-%d') AS reqdt,
       COUNT(svce_domain) countsvce
FROM bc_history
WHERE reqid ='MSYS'
GROUP BY reqdt WITH ROLLUP;
```

?

Total sum for a column will be the last row, with NULL value in `reqdt` column (which may be replaced with some literal, for example, 'Total').

> I want to use this query in Mybatis in Springboot. But my query send data only as alias name. So I need result as alias.

I understand nothing. But you may convert the query to the subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LEFT(CAST(reqdt AS UNSIGNED),8),'%Y-%m-%d') AS reqdt,
       COUNT(svce_domain) countsvce
FROM bc_history
WHERE reqid ='MSYS'
GROUP BY reqdt WITH ROLLUP
) AS subquery
ORDER BY reqdt IS NULL; -- place total row last
```

Now assign the alias by the common way, like this is a table, not a subquery.

Comment: I want to use this query in Mybatis in Springboot. But my query send data only as alias name. So I need result as alias.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It is very helpful to me!!